# Finalizar la recogida de datos al escribir un texto

Tags: c

Me piden que cree un programa que lea 10 números enteros tanto positivos como negativos ingresados por el teclado y presente su máximo, mínimo y promedio al finalizar.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, mayor, menor, suma=0;
    float promedio=0;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("Ingrese un  nùmero: " );
        scanf("%d", &num);
        suma= suma + num;
        if (i==0) {
            mayor = num;
            menor = num;
        }
        else {
            if (num > mayor) mayor = num;
            if (num < menor) menor = num;
        }
    }

    promedio = suma/10;
    printf("El numero mayor es: %d\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es: %d\n", menor);
    printf("El promedio es: %.2lf\n", promedio);

    return 0;
}
```

Luego me piden hacer que modifique el programa para que al ingresar el texto "salir" termine de inmediato sin presentar resultados; y al ingresar el texto "resultados" termine presentando los resultados. Esto ya no se como hacerlo, busque y busque por internet pero no comprendo muy bien, si es necesario cambiar todo el codigo para lograr esto lo hago, pero necesito ayuda porfavor! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tan solo tienes que leer una cadena de texto con `scanf` y luego ver si dice `resultados`. Si no, sales.

Para leer una cadena de texto:

```c
char comando[15];
scanf("%s", comando);
```

Y para comparar el contenido de una cadena sería:
`strcmp(comando, "resultados") == 0`

`strcmp` devuelve 0 si las cadenas son iguales. Devuelve un número negativo si la primera cadena es menor que la segunda, y un número positivo si la primera cadena es mayor que la segunda.

El final de tu código quedaría así:

```c
char comando[15];

printf("Escriba 'salir' para salir o 'resultados' para mostrar los resultados: ");
scanf("%s", comando);

if (strcmp(comando, "resultados") == 0) {
    promedio = suma/10;
    printf("El numero mayor es: %d\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es: %d\n", menor);
    printf("El promedio es: %.2lf\n", promedio);
}
```

Si necesitas otras cosas como añadir un bucle que repita hasta que el usuario diga "salir" o "resultados", pues habría que poner todo desde el printf hasta el final del `if` dentro de un bucle `do { ... } while((strcmp(comando, "resultados") != 0) && (strcmp(comando, "salir") != 0)`.

Comment: ¿y cómo compaginas la lectura del texto con la de los números?

Comment: Lo que yo he entendido es que lee los 10 números y luego puede elegir entre salir o mostrar los resultados. Y eso es lo que mi respuesta está haciendo. Tú solución es bastante más compleja, y no creo que sea lo que le están pidiendo. Admito que tu respuesta es más práctica y funcional, pero según mi interpretación no es la respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: también podría haber optado por leer todo como texto y convertirlo a números (que no es algo ni tan complicado ni tan extraño). Lo cierto es que teniendo en cuenta tu comentario me da la impresión que el enunciado es un poco ambiguo

Answer (score 3):

> Luego me piden hacer que modifique el programa para que al ingresar el texto "salir" termine de inmediato sin presentar resultados; y al ingresar el texto "resultados" termine presentando los resultados.

Lo que te están pidiendo aquí es que modifiques el programa para que pida números sin parar hasta que se introduzca **salir** o **resultados**.

Este resultado lo puedes conseguir de varias maneras.

Una forma es la que te muestro a continuación: Se lee un caracter de la entrada estándar y se comprueba:

- Si es un caracter de control o que no nos interesa (espacio, salto de línea, ...) se descarta, en caso contrario el caracter leído se reingresa en el buffer de entrada.
- Si es un dígito numérico se lee el número introducido por el usuario.
- Si es una letra, se lee el texto correspondiente y se comprueba con los esperados.

Dicho con código:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int mayor = INT_MIN;
  int menor = INT_MAX;
  int suma = 0;
  int total_numeros = 0;

  while( 1 )
  {
    char c = getchar();

    if( c == EOF ) // Detectamos CTRL + C
      break;
    if( c < '0' )  // descartamos caracteres de control, espacios, saltos de línea, ...
      continue;

    ungetc(c, stdin); // volvemos a poner el caracter en el buffer de la entrada estándar

    if( isdigit(c) )
    {
      int numero;
      scanf("%d", &numero);
      suma += numero;
      total_numeros++;
      if( numero > mayor ) mayor = numero;
      if( numero < menor ) menor = numero;
    }
    else
    {
      char texto[100];
      scanf("%s", texto);
      if( strcmp(texto, "salir") == 0 )
        break;

      if( strcmp(texto, "resultados") == 0 )
      {
        printf("El numero mayor es: %d\n", mayor);
        printf("El numero menor es: %d\n", menor);
        printf("El promedio es: %.2lf\n", suma / (double)total_numeros);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```